# How can I trigger a reversed animation when browser back button is press in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-animations, back-button

I have an AngularJS webapp where when `ngView` loads a page, the page slides from right to left.
And I would like the animation to reverse when the browser back button is pressed.

Could someone show me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: How are you performing animations? jQuery?

Comment: it says angularjs and css animations....... user could you check if the ng enter and ng leave classes are present when you press the back button?

Comment: SjoerdDeWit: the ng-animate and ng-enter, ng-leave classes do show up when I press the back button. Is there a way to detect browser back button? I'm guessing once I detect the browser back button I could just reverse the animation?